how do i bulk delete contacts rather than deleting each one individually?
i have customers who are now 6 years old, so due to data protection rules need to delete.
I can delete an individual contact using the actions, but don't want to delete hundreds one by one.
Is there any way i can select all contacts from a list and delete?

wondering if adding GDPR extension gives any 'find contacts not active in X years' easy solution

As above - the GDPR extension allows you to define criteria and you can then 'Forget' contacts in bulk from the extension dashboard. May be worth looking into

You use Find Contact or Advance Search to find all the contacts you want to delete.
On the search list you can either select all or select contact you want to delete
From the Actions drop-down you can choose Delete contact or Permanently delete contact.
HTH
Pradeep

